Using cookies from regular browser for scraping
I have made a script that scrapes www.coches.net using pyppeteer in python. This website detects me as a bot every few minutes and the only way I have found to bypass this detection is to extract the cookies from my normal browser and import them into the script. The problem is that every few minutes these stop working and I need to re-enter the web from the normal browser and extract them back to the script.  Is there any way to automate the process or any other solution?
This is the code:
import asyncio
import random
import json
import traceback
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer_stealth import stealth


async def puppeteer_cochesnet_scraper(start_url):
    print("Starting coches.net scrap...")

    browser = await launch(headless=True, executablePath='C:/Program Files/chrome-win/chrome.exe')
    context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()
    page = await context.newPage()

    with open('cookies_cochesnet.json', 'r') as f:
        cookies = json.load(f)

    await page.setCookie(*cookies)

    await page.setUserAgent(
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

    await page.setViewport({'width': 1280, 'height': 800})
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'Accept-Language': 'es-ES'})

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(
        'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) {'
        'success({coords: {latitude: 41.55049678876526, longitude: 2.447197735379941}});}'
    )

    await stealth(page)

    try:
        await page.goto(start_url, {'waitUntil': 'networkidle2'})
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Exception while navigating to URL: \n{ex}\nPassing URL...")
        print(f"Traceback details:\n{traceback.print_exc()}")

    finally:
        cookies = await page.cookies()
        with open("cookies_cochesnet.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(cookies, f)
        await browser.close()


I have tried the script to update the cookies but only the ones from the normal browser work. I had also thought to enter with selenium and extract the cookies when the web detects me but the web also detects me if I use selenium without headless and undetected-chromedriver mode.

Try using Undetected Chromedriver

I have already tested it but it detects it. @Daviid

Does it work if you run headfully? It seems like you're extracting and automating cookies already--what step is missing/failing?

The problem is that for it to work I need to extract the cookies from my normal browser (google chrome) and these only work for a few minutes. The cookies that the script saves at the end do not work, the web detects me if I use them. So for it to work I have to manually go to my browser and extract the cookies and import them to the script every few minutes. @ggorlen
